# vs code jupyter notebook output scroll

Tags: visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook, scroll, scrollbar

I have a question. When I run the code,[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JgQDh.png) my output slit by "/" and goes down. I want to scroll my output bar horizantally. How can I do that? Please help me. This is so annoying!!!

I tried many ways but I couldnt do :(